# Representation of negative Quantum entropy in terms of eigenvalues, i.e., $\text{Tr}(M\log M -M)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\lambda_i\log(\lambda_i)-\lambda_i)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Negative Quantum entropy or Negative Von Nuemann entropy is defined as $f(M)=\text{Tr}(M\log M -M)$.

Where $M$ is a positive definite matrix in $\mathbb{S}_+^n$, $\log$ is natural matrix logarithm for which $\log(M)$ is defined as $\log(M)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(\lambda_i)v_iv_i^T$ where $(\lambda_i,v_i)$ are eigenpairs of $M$.

Show  $f(M)=\text{Tr}(M\log M -M)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\lambda_i\log(\lambda_i)-\lambda_i)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $M\in\mathbb{S}_+^n$, there must exist an orthogonal matrix $U$ and a diagonal matrix $\Lambda=\text{diag}\left\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n\right\}$, with each $\lambda_j>0$, such that
$$
M=U\Lambda U^{\top}.
$$
Hence, using the definition of $\log M$,
\begin{align}
M\log M-M&=\left(U\Lambda U^{\top}\right)\left(U\log\Lambda\,U^{\top}\right)-U\Lambda U^{\top}\\
&=U\left(\Lambda\log\Lambda-\Lambda\right)U^{\top}.
\end{align}
Consequently,
\begin{align}
f(M)&=\text{tr}\left(M\log M-M\right)\\
&=\text{tr}\left(U\left(\Lambda\log\Lambda-\Lambda\right)U^{\top}\right)\\
&=\text{tr}\left(\left(\Lambda\log\Lambda-\Lambda\right)U^{\top}U\right)\\
&=\text{tr}\left(\Lambda\log\Lambda-\Lambda\right)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j\left(\log\lambda_j-1\right).
\end{align}

Comment: Excuse me but I think you miss understood this question. You have copied the irrelevant answer which is relevant to my other question. Please delete this answer so that others try to solve it.

Comment: @Saeed: Apologies for my misunderstanding. I corrected my answer. Perhaps you want to have a look at it. Besides, I would really appreciate it if you could explain your desired identity with this special case $M=I_n$ (I am afraid an additional "$-\lambda_i$" term is needed).

Comment: I think you are right but I am following this paper http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume6/tsuda05a/tsuda05a.pdf. On page 999, in the second line they have this equality. Am I missing something there?

Comment: @Saeed: I suspect the paper has some problem here, but not that serious. First, the choice of the quantum entropy in this paper seems unconventional. You may compare it with [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy). Secondly, it states an additional normalization condition $\text{tr}M=1$ at the 4th line from the last on page 998, with which we would have $f(M)=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j\log\lambda_j-1$. The constant $1$ could then be ignored since it appears to set some base level (like the potential energy).

Comment: The link is different. I think my question should be negative Von Neumann entropy. I revised them all.

Comment: @Saeed: Thanks for your follow-up. I think the negative sign is fine, while whether or not there should be an additional $-M$ in the main part matters -- and it brings difference. I would suppose the paper you refer to has made additional default assumptions (maybe not that default at all, like the normalization condition $\text{tr}M=1$), and the term $-M$ could thus be dropped. Anyway, thanks and good luck to you :-)

Comment: Have you looked my new question? Maybe you can help me? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3078707/how-to-show-texttrm-log-n-sum-i-1n-lambda-i-log-tilde-lambda-iu-i

Comment: @Saeed: Sure. I will have a look at it.

Comment: @Saeed: Forgive me, but it seems inappropriate to discuss under your new question. May I ask where the new desired identity comes from? Are you referring to equation (2.4) on page 999 in your paper? If so, perhaps the indices to take the summation include both $i$ and $j$?

Comment: You are right. I will revise it.

Comment: @Saeed: No worries :-)