# How to show $\text{Tr}(M\log N)=\sum_{i,j}^n\lambda_i\log(\tilde{\lambda_j})(u_i^{\top}\tilde{u}_j)^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

The above question is the equation $(2.4)$ of the following paper:

[MATRIX EXPONENTIATED GRADIENT UPDATES](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume6/tsuda05a/tsuda05a.pdf).

Let $M$ and $N$ be two $n \times n$ positive definite matrices where $M=U\Lambda U^{\top}$, $N=\tilde{U}\tilde{\Lambda} \tilde{U}^{\top} 
$ and $(\lambda_i,v_i)$ are eigenpairs of $M$, likewise for $N$.

How to show the following
$$\text{Tr}(M\log N)=\sum_{i,j}\lambda_i\log(\tilde{\lambda_j})(u_i^{\top}\tilde{u}_j)^2$$

First I do not know what $i,j$ mean in summation, and how we have it using two summations. Second how to get that.

My try:

\begin{align}
\text{Tr}(M\log N) &=
\text{Tr}(U\Lambda U^{\top}
\tilde{U}\log(\tilde{\Lambda})\tilde{U}^{\top}) \\
& = \text{Tr}(\Lambda U^{\top}
\tilde{U}\log(\tilde{\Lambda})\tilde{U}^{\top}U)
\end{align}

How can I proceed using matrix calculus to get the result not by expanding? what is the hidden trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To easy the notations, let us take
$$
\kappa_j=\log\tilde{\lambda}_j
$$
and
$$
v_j=\tilde{u}_j.
$$
With these notations, it suffices to show
$$
\text{tr}\left(M\log N\right)=\sum_{i,j=1}^n\lambda_i\kappa_j\left(u_i^{\top}v_j\right)^2.
$$

Now, let us begin our proof. Using
\begin{align}
M&=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_ju_ju_j^{\top},\\
N&=\sum_{j=1}^n\kappa_jv_jv_j^{\top},
\end{align}
we have
\begin{align}
\text{tr}\left(M\log N\right)&=\text{tr}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iu_iu_i^{\top}\sum_{j=1}^n\kappa_jv_jv_j^{\top}\right)\\
&=\text{tr}\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^n\lambda_i\kappa_ju_iu_i^{\top}v_jv_j^{\top}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i,j=1}^n\lambda_i\kappa_j\text{tr}\left(u_iu_i^{\top}v_jv_j^{\top}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i,j=1}^n\lambda_i\kappa_j\text{tr}\left(v_j^{\top}u_iu_i^{\top}v_j\right)\\
&=\sum_{i,j=1}^n\lambda_i\kappa_j\left(v_j^{\top}u_i\right)\left(u_i^{\top}v_j\right)\\
&=\sum_{i,j=1}^n\lambda_i\kappa_j\left(u_i^{\top}v_j\right)^2.
\end{align}
This completes the proof.

I would like to thank @loupblanc for kind advices.

Comment: Your proof is correct. 2 remarks: i) write $\log(N)=\cdots$ and ii) using Frobenius is useless because $u_i^Tv_j=v_j^Tu_i$.

Comment: @hypernova: Does the summation have $n^2$ terms?

Comment: @loupblanc: Thank you for your advices. I modified my answer as per your suggestions, credited to you.

Comment: @Saeed: Yes, the summation contains $n^2$ terms, and each of the indices $i$ and $j$ runs from $1$ to $n$. In other words, $\sum_{i,j=1}^n=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n$.

Answer (score 2):

The first version of the formula with one index is false. Take $M=\begin{pmatrix}50&37\\37&61\end{pmatrix},N=diag(2,1)$.

Comment: It is on page 999 of the following paper http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume6/tsuda05a/tsuda05a.pdf. Maybe I am wrong. Because I am confused about $i$ and $j$.

Comment: Yes, the correct formula is a sum with $2$ indices.